# IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa

while starting with spring rest I got following error as

```
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At
> least one JPA metamodel must be present!
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1595)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:566)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
> ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:736)
> [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
> [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
> [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1161)
> [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1150)
> [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.java.app.QuickPollApplication.main(QuickPollApplication.java:14)
> [classes/:na]
>     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:438) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.<init>(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:52)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:71)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1654)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1591)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>       ... 16 common frames omitted
```

with following code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class QuickPollApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuickPollApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testRest() {
        return "rest tested";
    }
```

and following is my pom.xml

UTF-8
            UTF-8
            1.8
        
    
    
        
            
                org.springframework.boot
                spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
            
            
                org.springframework.boot
                spring-boot-starter-web
            
            
                org.springframework.boot
                spring-boot-starter-web-services
            
    
            
                org.hsqldb
                hsqldb
                runtime
            
            
                org.springframework.boot
                spring-boot-starter-test
                test
            
            
                org.springframework
                spring-web
            
        
    
        
            
                
                    org.springframework.boot
                    spring-boot-maven-plugin
                
            
        
    
        
            
                spring-snapshots
                Spring Snapshots
                https://repo.spring.io/snapshot
                
                    true
                
            
            
                spring-milestones
                Spring Milestones
                https://repo.spring.io/milestone
                
                    false
                
            
        
        
            
                spring-snapshots
                Spring Snapshots
                https://repo.spring.io/snapshot
                
                    true
                
            
            
                spring-milestones
                Spring Milestones
                https://repo.spring.io/milestone
                
                    false

Please help me. I do not know how to solve this error

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have added

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in your pom.xml.

Spring boot will try automatically create an entity factory for JPA, but you do not have defined anything regarding JPA models.

Try removing it in order to test what have you done so far.

Afterwards you can check a tutorial using spring-data-starter-jpa like [this guy](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

Comment: since I am new to this, I am not able to find anything, can you point me in right direction, please

Answer (score 9):

I've fixed it by setting newer version of Hibernate.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can find a fully working example here:
https://github.com/zobarov/ptc-task-executor

Answer (score 7):

You can also disable Spring Data JPA's repository support by excluding the following auto configuration class (e.g. in your `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@SpringBootApplication` annotation)

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
```

For example:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```