# SpringBoot 2.0.2 At least one JPA metamodel must be present

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My parent POM is:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

I also added JPA:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When I start the application, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:741) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.bkates.ClashRoyaleSpringBootApplication.main(ClashRoyaleSpringBootApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:450) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.<init>(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:54) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:43) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:141) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I have an entity package with at least one entity.  I can't get the application to start.  What am I missing?

NOTE:  when I downgrade to 2.0.1 it works.  Is this a bug in 2.0.2??

Comment: Possible related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738818/illegalargumentexception-at-least-one-jpa-metamodel-must-be-present

Comment: @ThiagoProcaci I did see that article and tried their approach, but no luck.  I couldn't get it to work in 2.0.2, but it worked without change in 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue after deleted all hibernate-core folders under below directory:
.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core

and rebuilt my project.

Now, 2.0.2.RELEASE/2.0.3.RELEASE/2.0.4.RELEASE works fine.

Before I delete them, there are 4 versions of hibernate-core in the above folder. They are "4.3.6"/"5.0.12"/"5.2.17"/"5.3.4".

After I deleted them, there are "5.0.12"/"5.2.17"/"5.3.4" after rebuilt my projects.

And when I dig into this issue, I found that the "hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar" in previous "5.2.17" folder is bigger than the normal and it has no "hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar.sha1".

So, it may caused by poor network or poor mirror.